# splint whole program with a complex build process

Tags: c, makefile, lint, splint

I want to run splints whole program analysis on my system. However the system is quite large and different parts are compiled with different compiler defines and include paths. I can see how to convey this information to splint for a single file but I can't figure out how to do it for whole program. Does anyone know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a `Makefile` you could create a new target; then you would go through the actual compilation steps to *duplicate* them using Splint instead of the compiler.

My advice, however, is **against** the full-program approach. If you can isolate your system into separate parts, I'd rather start by checking them, one by one. Since your program is "quite large", expect a gazillion warnings... *for each one* of your modules. You will start to get rid of them once you have sprinkled your source code with the appropriate semantic annotations. Good luck! :)

Comment: I believe I was particularly looking for some output that is only produced in whole program mode. And I have many Makefiles, thousands of lines of the stuff, so extending the build process to understand split is not viable.

Comment: If you have a complex build process (say you autogenerate some source code files, copy or move another files around, etc.) there's no way Splint can automatically do that (or even know about). So I really believe that the only way left to go is by *mimicking* the build process (via Makefile).